# SerializationComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I am getting this error inside AS - even though I tripple checked to pick a valid version pairing (kotlin 1.2.40 with serialisation 0.5.0):

```
Error:Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: The provided plugin org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:186)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:418)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:265)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:399)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:920)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:950)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:397)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:361)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationComponentRegistrar.registerProjectComponents(Lcom/intellij/mock/MockProject;Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/config/CompilerConfiguration;)V
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:184)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your installed Kotlin plugin in the idea(Tools>Kotlin>Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates). Must be same as in your build.gradle file.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's an IntelliJ / Android Studio plugin that's made just for the Kotlin Serialization support, separate from the main Kotlin plugin.  From the [Working in IntelliJ IDEA](https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#working-in-intellij-idea) section of the readme:

> Because serialization is still highly experimental, it is shipped as a separate artifact from "big" Kotlin IDEA plugin. You can download additional IDEA plugin for working with projects that uses serialization from its TeamCity build page

It provides links to the latest TeamCity builds for this plugin, including [this one](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewLog.html?buildId=lastPinned&buildTypeId=KotlinTools_KotlinxSerialization_KotlinCompilerWithSerializationPlugin&tab=artifacts&guest=1&buildBranch=1.2.40) for Kotlin 1.2.40.

Since they only currently publish this plugin through TeamCity, you would have to install it manually by going to `Preferences` > `Plugins` > `Install plugin from disk...`

For anyone using IntelliJ instead of Android Studio, if the plugin doesn't solve the problem, the same readme says to:

> try to use gradle for running builds: `Settings` - `Build, Execution, Deployment` - `Build Tools` - `Gradle` - `Runner` - tick `Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle`; or launch builds from console.

There's an [open ticket](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/87) on Github about this error message, and it might also be worth keeping an eye on that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this *is* that plugin throwing the exception. At least, it is for me.